# A sequence that converges to the golden ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, golden-ratio

This is elementary, but I found it somewhat surprising.
Define
$$ a_n = \frac{1+ a_{n-2}}{\sqrt{1+a_{n-1}}} \;,$$
where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are constants.
For example, here is a plot for $a_1=5$ and $a_2=3$:

---

[image: Golden53]

---

It appears that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \approx 1.61803$, which is close to the
golden ratio $\phi$.
The limit appears to be independent
of the two initial values $a_1$ and $a_2$, which is the aspect I found
surprising. Of course $\frac{1+\phi}{\sqrt{1+\phi}}=\phi$, so it is not
so surprising that the limit is $\phi$.

> **Q**. For which values of $a_1$ and $a_2$ is $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \phi$?

Comment: Well, you've said that the final result is independent of $ a_1, a_2 $, so what are you trying to ask?

Comment: Since you want to show that $a_n \to \phi$, perhaps if you set $a_n = b_n+\phi$ you can show that $b_n \to 0$ using your identity for $\phi$.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. If there is a limit, then it is the golden ratio and this is independent of the initial values.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: "appears to be independent of $a_1,a_2$." I don't have a proof that it is. And I am not certain this is true for *all* $a_1,a_2$.

Comment: it is true for all non negative $a_1,a_2$

Comment: @chenbai: But certainly also for at least some negative numbers, e.g., $(a_1,a_2)=(-1,2)$.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke,Ya, $a_1,a_2 <-1$ is also OK.but it is not a big issue. you need to prove $a_n$ is converge first and then $a_n=\phi$ is obvious .